# How do I rescale cropped material with pdfcrop

Tags: scaling, pdfcrop

I'm running pdfcrop (version 1.31) on Mac OSX.  From what I read on [pdfcrop page](http://pdfcrop.sourceforge.net/) I should be able to rescale the size of the final document.  The suggested approach is

`pdfcrop infile.pdf letter outfile.pdf`

to rescale the final version to fit to letter.  When I try this I get the errror

```
PDFCROP 1.31, 2010/09/17 - Copyright (c) 2002-2010 by Heiko Oberdiek.
!!! Error: Too many files!
```

Many people are posting nicely cropped snippets of their final results.  My cropped material pales.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`PDFCrop`](http://pdfcrop.sourceforge.net/) is different from the [`pdfcrop`](http://mirror.ctan.org/help/Catalogue/entries/pdfcrop.html) you are using. The latter does not rescale, it is just a Perl script that uses ghostscript `bbox` device to get the bounding box and uses it to crop the PDF file. There are options for specifying margins or bounding boxes, but rescaling is not part of them.

This can be achieved by a driver file for package `pdfpages`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{the-cropped-file}
\end{document}
```

Additional margins can be achieved by either using option `--margins` for `pdfcrop` or `trim` for `\includepdf` (documented in [`grfguide`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/graphics/grfguide.pdf) for `\includegraphics`).

Comment: That's perfect.  Not sure what `\includepdf` does.  I'll have to look at the documentation for that. But even without that line, I get a far more desirable result.  Thank you!